# Dealing with nuisance variables in a MANOVA situation

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multivariate-analysis, manova, mediation

I have a study in which participants facebook profiles were rated by a group of students. The participants were then randomly allocated into one of three groups: the **uncertain condition** (where they could have been assigned either a liked-best or liked-least rating but they are not told which one), the **Liked-Best condition** (where they assigned the highest rating) and the **Liked-Least condition** (where they are assigned the lowest rating).

Once they saw their ratings they completed a measure of mood and then in turn were able to rate how attractive they found the facebook profiles of those who rated them. After this they completed a measure of attachment style (ECR-S), self-esteem (RSES), the mood measure for a second time, and a measure of how much they had thought about the rating group in the last 15 minutes.

The **dependent variables** in the study are **attraction levels** and **reported thoughts** of the participants to the rating group of students, as well as an **overall measure of mood** (mood across both time points summed and averaged).

**Please bear with me as I am a complete novice at statistics, but the analysis of the data has me extremely confused.**

My **IV** in the study is **Condition**, in that I want to see whether there was a significant difference between groups on the dependent variables.

However I also have the measures of attachment style and self-esteem, the data for which my supervisor is planning on using in future studies but also wants me to include in mine. The problem is, I do not know where they fit in!

Originally I thought that any effect of uncertainty on the DVs may be mediated by attachment style and self-esteem, BUT because the measurements were taken after the ratings had been given, they aren't exactly IVs as they may well have been affected by the ratings given.

Please any help on how to analyse this would be much appreciated. I have been told I should use separate ANOVAs, but I do not feel this is justified due to the familywise inflation of the Type I error rate. I was thinking of using MANOVA to analyse Attraction and Reported thoughts (correlated at r = .34, p < .01) by Condition, with a one-way ANOVA for mood by condition. But then I am not sure how to deal with attachment style and self-esteem. Please Help!

Comment: I don't understand the 1st paragraph with experimental methodology, what the groups mean, or how you assign a participant to a group.  Can you clarify?  Also, it would help to tell us about what is the range of possible values for each dependent variable (is it continuous?  one of a set of fixed values, like 1-5?  one from a set of categories)

Comment: If you want to know how attachment style and self-esteem might fit in, you should start by talking to your supervisor about how he/she sees them fitting in.  Statistical analysis should be based upon a theoretical model/hypothesis.  Perhaps your supervisor's hypothesis is that the attachment style and/or self-esteem of the participants may affect attraction level, reported thoughts, or mood of the participants?  To find out, you'd have to talk to your supervisor.

Comment: Basically participants were recruited under the premise that their Facebook profile was going to be shown to a group of students at another institution who would rate it according to certain criteria (however at no time did anyone other than me see the student's profiles). Once I had the 'ratings' from these students I contacted each participant to let them know their ratings had been completed and sent them the link for the surveys. Students were assigned to the groups randomly by the survey website.

Comment: Attraction was rated using two items on a 10-point Likert scale, the results were then summed and averaged. So the attraction rating ranged between 1 to 10. Reported thoughts was similar with participants indicating how much they had thought about the rating group in the last 15 minutes on one item using a 9-point Likert scale. Mood was assessed using the POMS-SF which is scored on a 5-point Likert scale from 0 - 4, the scoring of the POMS is such that participants in a better mood will end up with a negative score and participants in a worse mood will end up with a positive score.

Comment: My supervisor is unavailable to me until the end of semester as she is on leave and my fill-in supervisor has really no idea about the construct I am studying. So unfortunately I can't get a hold of her to ask.